# Splitting a list at given index f#

Tags: f#

For a class I'm following, I have to do the following exercise:

> Implement a function
>
> ```
> let splitAt (i : int) (l : List<'a>) : List<'a> * List<'a> = ...
> ```
>
> that splits the list into two lists, the rst one containing all the elements of l from position 0 to position i
>   included, and the second one containing all the remaining elements. The two resulting lists are returned
>   in a tuple. For example:
>
> split 3 [3;5;4;-1;2;2] = ([3;5;4;-1],[2;2])

We have to do these problems only using functional programming, and thus I'm not allowed to use pre-existing functions.

I have the following code which seems to me to (logically) be correct:

```
let splitAt (i:int)(l: List<'a>): List<'a> * List<'a> = 
    let rec loop n startlist restlist = 
        if n = i then
            restlist * startlist
        else
            match startlist with
            | h :: t -> loop (n+1) [t] [(restlist :: h)]
            | h :: [] -> None
    loop 0 l []
```

and below my `[<EntryPoint>]`

```
printfn "%A" (splitAt stringlist 3)
```

However, this gives me a couple of errors, namely:

> None of the types `'a list`, `'a list` support the operator `*`
>   This expression was expected to have type    `int`    but here has type    `char list`
>   This expression was expected to have type    `List<'a>`    but here has type    `int`

Answer (score 1):

The `*` operator is used for declaring a tuple type, but when you're building a tuple you use `,` instead. So you want `restlist, startlist`.

Then you'll discover that there's another type error, because one branch of your `match` expression returns `None`. That's an option type, so the value you return should be a `Some`. So you want `Some (restlist, startlist)`.

And now you'll discover one more type error, which is that you've declared that the function returns a tuple but in fact it returns a tuple option (that is, either `None` or `Some tuple`). So your type declaration needs to become `(List<'a> * List<'a>) option`.

For more on why `*` is used in declaring tuple types rather than `,`, https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/tuples/ is a good read.

Comment: Since this is for a class, I haven't looked at whether or not your logic is correct; you'll learn best by figuring that out for yourself anyway. I've limited myself to helping you with the syntax, so that the code is what you clearly intended to write, whether correct or not.

Comment: Fixing the type issues pointed out, you will be really close. A few small pointers `| h :: [] -> None` is a case against `startList`, which is a list. You are wanting to match on an empty list which is just`[]`.

Comment: And 1 more tip for working with lists: If you want to append a value to another list you need `(restlist @ [h])` rather than `::`. Good luck!